# Common Mahjong wait patterns

Tags: mahjong, riichi-mahjong

In endgame, you typically have a hand in tenpai that is waiting for 1 more tile to be complete. Usually, it is better if you are able to wait for multiple tiles so your chance to finish are increased. From the rules, some typical wait patterns are derived. For instance, if you got 3 sets and a pair and an incomplete 23, you're waiting for either 1 or 4 to complete a chii (street).

Experienced players know that certain patterns lead to especially high chances to finish. What are the most common patterns to know and strive for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a basic answer on my question [over here](http://www.sloperama.com/mjfaq/mjfaq08.htm):

> Try to go out waiting for multiple
>   tiles (not just one). Imagine that you
>   have three complete sets and two
>   pairs. Imagine that one pair is 2
>   Bams, and you draw a 3 Bam from the
>   wall -- which tile do you discard now?
>   In this situation, many experienced
>   players will discard a 2 Bam, keeping
>   2-3. A two-way incomplete chow call is
>   better than a two-pair call.
>
> Learn to
>   shape the hand into calling patterns
>   that give you multiple chances to win,
>   such as the following:
>
> ```
> Tiles in hand     Call for 
>
> 2223              134 
> 2224              34 
> 2223344           2345 
> 2223334           2345 
> 2223456           14736 
> 22234 RR          25 R 
> 23456             147** 
> 34567             258** 
> 45678             369**
> ```
>
> Highly skilled players of
>   un-American mah-jongg (since American
>   style alone does not use "chows") know
>   these patterns by heart. More complex
>   call shapes are mostly extensions of
>   these. Although the American game does
>   not use chows, the strategy of having
>   a multiple-tile call still applies to
>   that game as well.
>
> Of special interest
>   is the complexity of the pure hand. If
>   you're working on a pure hand, it can
>   often be difficult to tell what all
>   the tiles are that can complete the
>   hand. For instance:
>   1-2-3-4-5-5-5-6-6-6-7-8-9 (5 chances);
>   1-2-3-4-5-5-5-5-6-6--7-8-9 (5
>   chances); 2-3-4-4-4-5-5-5-6-6-6-7-8 (7
>   chances); and of course
>   1-1-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-9-9 (9 chances).

**Edit: Additional links with a lot more waits**

- http://saki.wikia.com/wiki/Mahjong_waits
- http://saki.wikia.com/wiki/Complex_waits
- http://www.reachmahjong.com/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=52599

Especially the latter is, from my beginner eyes, insanely exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

**Update January 2023:**

There is a Mahjong Waits Infographic which shows common patterns:
[image: Common and Useful Mahjong Wait Patterns]

Links: [PNG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K4NuE2UZgeqhSR-WsYWyQlRiEERh5VQo/view?usp=share_link) | [PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MXvEAwT31RnTJzCqYTpfaL7bd7cmONjT/view?usp=share_link) | [Author's post (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/Mahjong/comments/100qw6y/mahjong_waits_infographic/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

**Original answer**

As an additional resource, I created a tool for finding the waits needed to complete a hand: https://mahjong-trainer.netlify.app

It generates random tenpai hands, so you indicate the waits and the site will tell you the correct answer. And after some tries you'll start to spot some wait patterns.

Screenshot:

[image]